# Google Play Console OnePlatformRpcException

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-console

I add a new app and I can't do anything because of the above error on google play console

> OnePlatformRpcException: status: code: 13 message: Internal error encountered. , request: RpcRequestz_play.console.apps.api.pricing.PricingService_GetBillableCountries, httpStatus: 500, stackTrace: null

[image]

**Can anyone come across this problem and solve it? I think this is an error from Google.**

Comment: I would contact the Google support and ask for help if that error doesn't go away by itself after one hour. Recently had a similar error myself, while contacting the Google support the error disappeared.

Comment: @grill2010  As you said yes, as soon as I sent feedback to the support team, my error message changed. but my problem is not resolved : OnePlatformRpcException: status: code: 9 message: Precondition check failed. , request: RpcRequestz_play.console.apps.api.payments.PaymentsService_ListPaymentsAlerts, httpStatus: 400, stackTrace: null

Comment: I think that only the Google support team can help you out here as this seems to be an internal problem.